# Copying a powerpoint file

Tags: python, backup, powerpoint, copying

I am currently trying to work on a program to automatically copy a PowerPoint into another file when ran however I cannot use shutil as it cannot handle pptx files any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52882102/edit) your question to include code you have already tried.

Comment: What do you mean by “it cannot copy the pptx file”?

Comment: I am trying to make a program that can copy a pptx file from one destination to another

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the file?

```
import os
os.popen('copy .\\file1.txt .\\test\\file1.txt')
```

If you're trying to move ALL .pptx files in a directory to a backup, something like this might work for a more, hassle-free method:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "./"
included_extensions = ['pptx','PPTX']
allFiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if any(f.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)]
length = len(allFiles)

for i in range(length):
    os.popen('copy .\\'+allFiles[i]+' .\\backup\\'+allFiles[i])
```